# SwiftUI - Can I have a tab bar show on iPhone and sidebar show on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I Am developing a SwiftUI App for iOS that runs on iPhone and iPad. I am wondering if it is possible to show a tab bar on iPhone, but show a vertical side bar on iPad to make better use of the large screen. The tab bar and the side bar would have the same functionality, switching between tabs. It could look something like this [Image I found on twitter](https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1278136759671566336/pu/img/bXutEVuiivXiVFbQ.jpg) except I don't need to have a macOs version of it. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Work on your AppDelegate where you select a view depending on the device type (iPhone or iPad).

Comment: Do you mean a tabBar that is vertical for iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach to have explicitly separated views for different devices

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            YourSidebarView()
        } else {
            YourTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add conditional check, somthing like folling:

```
struct TabSideBar: View {

    #if os(iOS)
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    #endif
    
    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            TabBarContentView()
        } else {
            SideBarContentView()
        }
        #else //MacOSView
            SideBarContentView()
        #endif
    }
    
}
```